# Create a meeting with attendees automatically from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an event with a guest automatically when my macro is executed. I've been trying to create an event with a guest automatically during the execution of my macro, but it doesn't work.

I always get errors and the guest is never "invited".

It's probably a minor issue, but these are the two versions I've done so far.

Do you see an error that I haven't seen?
Thanks

Version 1

```
Sub Reminder_ContactCustomer()

Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(1)
myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
myItem.Subject = "TO DO " + Range("B25").Value + " CONTACT CUSTOMER"
myItem.Location = "OFFICE 1A"
myItem.Start = Range("H25").Value
myItem.Duration = 90

Set myOptionalAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("mail@domain.ch")
myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional
myItem.Send

End Sub
```

Version 2

```
Sub Reminder_ContactCustomerV2()

Dim I As Long
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutItem As Object
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xRg = Range("B28:H28")
For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
Set xOutItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(1)
Debug.Print xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value
xOutItem.Subject = "TO DO " + Range("C9").Value + " CONTACT CUSTOMER"
xOutItem.Location = "OFFICE 1A"
xOutItem.Start = xRg.Cells(I, 7).Value
xOutItem.AllDayEvent = True
xOutItem.Duration = 15
xOutItem.BusyStatus = 2
xOutItem.ReminderSet = True
xOutItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
xOutItem.Body = "Auto reminder added by the Excel Checklist"
Set myRequiredAttendee = xOutItem.Recipients.Add("mail@domain.ch")
myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired
xOutItem.Sent
xOutItem.Save
Set xOutItem = Nothing
Next
Set xOutApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: suggest you try to save before sending in the first example. 2nd example uses .Sent instead of .Send, which will just return the Sent (time) property.

Comment: Thanks @tnavidi, for the first example I get the error 424 ; Object Required. But unfortunately this does not seem to work for the second example

Comment: Object required? Did you put `myItem.Save` ? or just `save`? it should be `myItem.Save`, (I haven't tried the code myself, yet)

Comment: Yes I added the myItem.Save  (No worries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked when i tried it myself (using option explicit to uncover mispells etc)

```
Sub Reminder_ContactCustomer()

Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim myOptionalAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(1)
myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
myItem.Subject = "TO DO " + Range("B25").Value + " CONTACT CUSTOMER"
myItem.Location = "OFFICE 1A"
myItem.start = Range("H25").Value
myItem.Duration = 90

Set myOptionalAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("mail@domain.ch")
myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional
myItem.Send

End Sub
```

you need `Set` in front of `myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(1)`
and consistent myOlApp (you used xOutApp at the beginning)

Comment: Also, i changed range("B25").value and Range("H25").value with some examples as i don't have the sheet you've used

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! But do you also have this error with your code : User-Defined type not defined ?

Comment: No, you might need to add Outlook to References. Mine says Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library, i suppose the version may vary depending on which one you use.

Comment: I actually went to activate two three other Outlooks in the reference list and it is in order, it works perfectly!  Thanks